# C# Is it safe to call 'BackgroundWorker' inside 'using' statement?

Tags: c#, windows-services, backgroundworker

I have developed a windows service. In the service I was using a BackgroundWorker to Post data in my Database.
I declared a BackgroundWorker inside my database constructor class and was using that whenever needed.
During the test I got one error:

> This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks
>   concurrently

I tried to find out the solution and many people suggest to use new instance for each task. I changed my code like:

```
        ...
        using (BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker())
        {
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bkDoPost);
            bw.RunWorkerAsync(dbobj);
        }
        ...
```

and my 'bkDoPost' is:

```
void bkDoPost(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        dbObject dbj = e.Argument as dbObject;
        this.db.Insert(dbj.tableName, dbj.data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logs.logMessage("There was an error in data post. See the ErrorLog");
        logs.logError(ex);
    }
}
```

The code works fine during test.

My question is am I doing correct way?

OR Is there any issue doing in that way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. Your background worker will be disposed before your work completes.

It is better to call `Dispose` manually after the work completes.

Better still, consider using a different scheme for handling asynchronous work. Background worker is becoming obsolete and is targeted at UI applications, rather than services. The restriction on parallel operations highlights the intention of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the BackgroundWorker into a using statement. Instead put the Dispose() call into the RunWorkerCompleted event.

Nevertheless BackgroundWorker is maybe not the best thing to use in your case, cause it is primilary use is to run some buisness code while the UI stays responive and to automatically update the UI within the RunWorkerCompeleted event.

If you don't need to interfere with the UI when the job is finished or you have a lot of smaller jobs to be done it would be more efficient to switch to encapsulate your jobs within [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)s.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver this is service consumed by client application. When it get a request it logs the information to database and returns the response to the client request. The database resides on a remote server so it may takes longer to post the data that's why i decided to post data in background.

Comment: @lqbal: Then switch to Task.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many updates, creating one BackgroundWorker for each one could be very time and memory consuming.
I would use an independant thread that I would wake up each time an update has to be done :

```
Queue<DbWork> dbUpdates = new Queue<DbWork>();
EventWaitHandle waiter = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
...
// Init :
new Thread(new ThreadStart(DbUpdateWorker));
...

private void DbUpdateWorker()
{
    while (true)
    {
        DbWork currentWork = null;
        lock (dbUpdates)
        {
            if (dbUpdates.Count > 0)
                currentWork = dbUpdates.Dequeue();
        }

        if (currentWork != null)
        {
            currentWork.DoWork();
        }

        if (dbUpdates.Count == 0)
        {
            waiter.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}

public void AddWork(DbWork work)
{
    lock (dbUpdates)
    {
        dbUpdates.Enqueue(work);
    }
    waiter.Set();
}
```

Comment: Creating new objects isn't a performance concern until you get into truly wild numbers. Arithmetic and IO are the biggest blockers. The current trend is to create a new `Task` for each unit of work. Creating a `Task` involves leasing a semaphore from the OS, yet performance is acceptable. Why is this? The asynchronous work they encapsulate is usually orders of magnitude more expensive - the setup time is cheap in comparison.